# Differentiate a Variable Limit Ito Integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider a variable limit integral $I(t)=\int\limits_0^{\phi(t)}M(s)dW(s)$,

where $\phi(t)$ is an increasing deterministic function with $\phi(0)=0$, the integrand $M(t)$ is stochastic, and $W(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion. Assume that $M(t)$ and $W(t)$ are adapted to filtration $\mathscr{F}_t$.

I am unsure whether I can differentiate this integral as usual, i.e. $dI(t)=M(\phi(t))\phi^{'}(t)dW(t)$.

If not, what should I do to get the limit of the integral rid of those functions.

Comment: I am not sure if $I$ is even adapted to the filtration to which $M$ and $W$ are adapted.

Comment: Let's just assume all the processes here adapt to a filtration $\mathscr{F}_t$.

Comment: What I am worried about is, for instance, the following situation: Simply choose $M \equiv 1$ and $\phi(t) = 0$, $\psi(t) = 2t$. Then $I(t) = W(2t)$ is *not* adapted to the filtration $\mathscr{F}_t$ even if $M$ and $W$ are.

Comment: It may be a problem in some cases. (I simplify the question so that only the upper limit is variable.) Under this condition, the adaptivity of $I(t)$ has anything to do with the differentiation?

Comment: I mean, in the original case, there might be some problems if the functions are not monotonous or take negative values. But now we just say $I(t)$ is adapted to the filtration $\mathscr{F}_{\phi(t)}$.

Comment: Ito process is basically an adapted process, but now I am not sure if adaptability will ever matter in your question. Both $I(t)$, $M(\phi(t))$ and $W(\phi(t))$ are $\mathscr{F}_{\phi(t)}$-adapted so at least the formulation of the question itself has no issue. I am also curious about the answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot write it in this form, but using random time change, you can write it in another form as follows. By Theorem 8.5.7 of Oksendall's book, you can write
$$I_t = \int_0^t M_{\phi(s)}\sqrt{\phi'(s)}d\tilde B_s,$$
where $\tilde B_t = \int_0^{\phi(t)} \sqrt{(\phi^{-1})'(s)}dW_s$ is another Brownian motion (let $\alpha_t:=\phi(t)$ in the theorem). In this form, you can write 
$$dI_t = M_{\phi(t)}\sqrt{\phi'(t)}d\tilde B_t.$$
You don't even need that $I_t$ is adapted to the filtration of $W_t$ (which holds if and only if $\phi(t)\leq t$).